# change a list of two elements each into a dataframe of two columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have run the following code in R :

```
vol_final <- list()
year = data_hv$Year
library(dplyr)




for (i in 2000:2022) {
  
  
  data_hv_i <- data_hv %>% filter(year == i)
  
  price_i = data_hv_i$Wheat
  ret <- log(lag(price_i)) - log(price_i)
  vol_i <- sd(ret, na.rm = TRUE) * sqrt(nrow(data_hv_i)) * 100
  
  
  vol_final  <- append(vol_final, list(data.frame(year = i, vol_i)))
}

vol_final
```

I thus obtain a list of 23 dataframes each having 1 row and 2 columns (first column being the year, the 2nd one vol_i, for each i). I would like to obtain something that resembles this :

```
year               volatility

2000               120
2001               128
2002               114
```

Could anyone help ?

Comment: you have `dplyr` loaded. Why do you need a for loop? just do `data_hv %>%group_by(Year) %>%%>%summarise(volatility = sd(log(lag(Wheat)) - log(Wheat), na.rm = TRUE) * sqrt(n()) * 100)`

Answer (score 0):

We use `rbind()` to bind add the rows from **two** dataframes together. (The column names must be the same). To perform this on multiple dataframes, we add `do.call()`.

##### example data

```
df_list <- list( data.frame(year=2000, volatility=120),
                 data.frame(year=2001, volatility=128),
                 data.frame(year=2002, volatility=114))

> df_list

[[1]]
  year volatility
1 2000        120

[[2]]
  year volatility
1 2001        128

[[3]]
  year volatility
1 2002        114
```

##### bind rows

```
do.call(rbind, df_list)


> do.call(rbind, df_list)

  year volatility
1 2000        120
2 2001        128
3 2002        114
```